# Get actual playtime of webrtc stream

Tags: javascript, webrtc, gstreamer

I am streaming video from gstreamer to the rtsp, convert it to the webrtc and show the video in the website. I need to know what is the time from the beginning of the stream to synchronize with some additional metadata.

When I connect to the stream 10 seconds after the streaming started for example, I need to know that the delay between start and my delay is exactly 10 seconds.

How can I get such information?

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.

- [Insertable Streams](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6321945865879552) and insert metadata with each frame. I would use a `identity` element and modify in the `handoff`.
- [requestVideoFrameCallback](https://web.dev/requestvideoframecallback-rvfc/) this allows you to get exact timing information. `presentationTime` is probably what you want, but other values might be useful.

Comment: Hi Sean, the rerequestVideoFrameCallback looks promising, I think I am close. Thank you! I have tried this code snippet, trying to get a presentationTime. But whenever I make a window refresh, this timer starts from 0. But what I need is to retain the information of time and not reset it back to zero. Could you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: const doSomethingWithTheFrame = (now, metadata) => {
  console.log(now, metadata.presentationTime);
  videoElem.requestVideoFrameCallback(doSomethingWithTheFrame);
};
videoElem.requestVideoFrameCallback(doSomethingWithTheFrame);

Comment: if it helps, there is a gst pipeline which I am using for testing. 
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///buffer/video.mp4 ! nvvideoconvert ! nvv4l2h264enc ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:8554/stream

to go from rtsp to webrtc, I am using this project- https://github.com/deepch/RTSPtoWebRTC . Is there anything in the pipeline what will help? Will switching to pion help?

Comment: you may want captureTime from requestVideoFrameCallback but that may require an arcane header extension and the only way to find out is to inspect the chrome source code.